# Spring Integration Flow with Jdbc Message source which has dynamic query

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow, oracle-cdc

I am trying to do a change data capture from oracle DB using spring cloud data flow with kafka as broker. I am using polling mechanism for this. I am polling the data base with a basic select query at regular intervals to capture any updated data. For a better fail proof system, I have persisted my last poll time in oracle DB and used it to get the data which is updated after last poll.

```
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter =
            new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, this.properties.getQuery());
    jdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setUpdateSql(this.properties.getUpdate());
    return jdbcPollingChannelAdapter;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(3000)));
    flowBuilder.channel(this.source.output());
    flowBuilder.transform(trans,"transform");
    return flowBuilder.get();

}
```

My queries in application properties are as below:

```
query: select * from kafka_test where LAST_UPDATE_TIME >(select LAST_POLL_TIME from poll_time)

update : UPDATE poll_time SET LAST_POLL_TIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This working perfectly for me. I am able to get the CDC from the DB with this approach.

The problem I am looking over now is below:

Creating an table just to maintain the poll time is an overburden. I am looking for maintaining this last poll time in a kafka topic and retrieve that time from kafka topic when I am making the next poll.

I have modified the `jdbcMessageSource` method as below to try that:

```
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    String query = "select * from kafka_test where LAST_UPDATE_TIME > '"+<Last poll time value read from kafka comes here>+"'";

    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter =
            new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, query);
    return jdbcPollingChannelAdapter;
}
```

But the Spring Data Flow is instantiating the pollingFlow( ) (please see the code above) bean only once. Hence what ever the query that is run first will remain the same. I want to update the query with new poll time for each poll.

Is there a way where I can write a custom `Integrationflow` to have this query updated everytime I make a poll ?

I have tried out `IntegrationFlowContext` for that but wasn't successful.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Artem's answer for the mechanism for a dynamic query in the standard adapter; an alternative, however, would be to simply wrap a `JdbcTemplate` in a Bean and invoke it with

```
IntegrationFlows.from(myPojo(), "runQuery", e -> ...)
    ...
```

or even a simple lambda

```
    .from(() -> jdbcTemplate...)
```

Comment: See my answer, please,

Comment: @Gary Russell Thanks a lot for your answer. That really helped us solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of both the answer above, I was able to figure out the approach.
Write a `jdbc template` and wrap that as a bean and use it for the `Integration Flow`.

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StockSource {

  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  private MessageChannelFactory messageChannelFactory;  // You can use normal message channel which is available in spring cloud data flow as well.

  private List<String> findAll() {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String time = "10/24/60" . (this means 10 seconds for oracle DB)
    String query = << your query here like.. select * from test where (last_updated_time > time) >>;
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<String>() {
      @Override
      public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          ...
          ...
          any row mapper operations that you want to do with you result after the poll.
          ...
          ...
          ...
        // Change the time here for the next poll to the DB. 
        return result;
      }
    });
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow supplyPollingFlow() {

    IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows
        .from(this::findAll, spec -> {
          spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000));
        });
    flowBuilder.channel(<<Your message channel>>);
    return flowBuilder.get();
  }

}
```

In our use case, we were persisting the last poll time in a kafka topic. This was to make the application state less. Every new poll to the DB now, will have a new time in the `where` condition.

P.S: your messaging broker (kafka/rabbit mq) sdould be running in your local or connect to them if there are hosted on a different platform.

God Speed !!!

Answer (score 1):

We have this test configuration (sorry, it is an XML):

```
<inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=:status" channel="target"
                             data-source="dataSource" select-sql-parameter-source="parameterSource"
                             update="delete from item"/>


    <beans:bean id="parameterSource" factory-bean="parameterSourceFactory"
                factory-method="createParameterSourceNoCache">
        <beans:constructor-arg value=""/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="parameterSourceFactory"
                class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
        <beans:property name="parameterExpressions">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="status" value="@statusBean.which()"/>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="sqlParameterTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="status" value="#{ T(java.sql.Types).INTEGER}"/>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="statusBean"
                class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.config.JdbcPollingChannelAdapterParserTests$Status"/>
```

Pay attention to the `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` and its `createParameterSourceNoCache()` factory. The this result can be used for the `select-sql-parameter-source`.

The `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` has a `setSelectSqlParameterSource` on the matter.

So, you configure a `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` to be able to resolve some query parameter as an expression for some bean method invocation to get a desired value from Kafka. Then `createParameterSourceNoCache()` will help you to obtain an expected `SqlParameterSource`.

There is some info in docs as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter